# How can I pass an array of addresses from one contract into another?

Tags: solidity

I have a contract A that has a mapping and an array of addresses.
I want to pass them into contract B, and perform some calculations with them every time contract B receives money.

How can I do that?

```
contract A {
  mapping (address => uint256) _balances;
  address[] internal _holders;
}

contract B {
  receive () {
     for (let i = 0; i < _holders.length; i++) {
      if (_balances[_holders[i]] > 100) {
         //do something
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you could create a function in `contract A` that when called will return a list of holders that have > 100 balance.

But finally, the implementation you settle on is really going to depend on the scale of your data. E.g. if there are many holders, but only a few of them will have > 100 balance, it might make sense to keep track of them in an [EnumerableSet](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.6.0/contracts/utils/structs/EnumerableSet.sol) called e.g. `richHolders`, which you would only update when an account’s balance crosses the 100 line in either direction. You could then have `contract A` expose `richHolders` to `contract B`.

On the other hand, if `richHolders` is going to be very large, `B.receive` is going to be very heavy on gas. A preferable pattern would be something like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.15;

contract A {
  mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
}

contract B {
    A immutable private _a;

    constructor(A a) {
        _a = a;
    }

    uint256 num = 0;

    struct ReceiveCall {
        address msgSender;
        uint256 msgValue;
        mapping(address => bool) didSomething;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => ReceiveCall) private _receiveCalls;

    receive() external payable {
        ReceiveCall storage thisReceiveCall = _receiveCalls[num++];
        thisReceiveCall.msgSender = msg.sender;
        thisReceiveCall.msgValue = msg.value;
    }

    function doSomething(uint256 receiveCallNum) external {
        require(_a.balances(msg.sender) > 100);
        ReceiveCall storage receiveCall = _receiveCalls[receiveCallNum];
        require(!receiveCall.didSomething[msg.sender]);
        // do something with previous receive data
        receiveCall.didSomething[msg.sender] = true;
    }
}
```

In this way, `receive` is kept light, and then rich holders can call and pay for `doSomething` themselves.

P.S. In my suggested solution, the list of rich holders might change between the time `receive` is called and the time the individual rich holders call `doSomething`. So the behaviour is different than yours. But maybe you can find a way to reuse the concept of devising a *pull* solution instead of a *push* solution, rather than reusing the exact code itself. This was the intention of my answer.